# Save logging DEBUG and show only logging INFO Python

Tags: python, logging

I would like to save in superwrapper.log all logging lines but only show in console the INFO.
If I remove the `#` of filename line , the file is okey but I don't see anything in the console.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    logging.basicConfig(
        #filename='superwrapper.log',
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s %(module)s - %(funcName)s: %(message)s',
        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    )

2020-04-28 11:41:09.698 INFO common - handle_elasticsearch: Elastic connection detected
2020-04-28 11:41:09.699 INFO superwrapper - <module>: Cookies Loaded: |TRUE|
2020-04-28 11:41:09.715 DEBUG connectionpool - _new_conn: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): m.facebook.com:443
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use multiple handlers. [logging.basicConfig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) can accept `handlers` as an argument starting in Python 3.3. One is required for logging to the log file and one to the console. You can also set the handlers to have different logging levels. The simplest way I can think of is to do this:

```
import logging
import sys

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('superwrapper.log')
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s %(module)s - %(funcName)s: %(message)s',
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    handlers=[
        file_handler,
        console_handler
    ]
)
```

One thing to note is the `StreamHandler` writes to strerr. Usually you will want to override this with `sys.stdout`

Answer (score 1):

You can set up multiple loggers. This will get rid of the DEBUG messages, but note that messages of a higher severity will still be broadcast (e.g. 'WARNING' and 'ERROR').

This exact scenario is in the [logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-multiple-destinations) of the Python docs:

```
import logging

# set up logging to file - see previous section for more details
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
                    filename='/temp/myapp.log',
                    filemode='w')
# define a Handler which writes INFO messages or higher to the sys.stderr
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# set a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
# tell the handler to use this format
console.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

# Now, we can log to the root logger, or any other logger. First the root...
logging.info('Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.')

# Now, define a couple of other loggers which might represent areas in your
# application:

logger1 = logging.getLogger('myapp.area1')
logger2 = logging.getLogger('myapp.area2')

logger1.debug('Quick zephyrs blow, vexing daft Jim.')
logger1.info('How quickly daft jumping zebras vex.')
logger2.warning('Jail zesty vixen who grabbed pay from quack.')
logger2.error('The five boxing wizards jump quickly.')
```

In the example given by the cookbook, you should see in the console all the 'INFO', 'WARNING' and 'ERROR' messages, but only the log file will hold the 'DEBUG' message.

Answer (score 0):

@Alan's answer was great, but it also wrote the message from the root logger, which was too much for me, because I was afraid that the size of log file would get out of control. So I modified it like below to only log what I specified and nothing extra from the imported modules.

```
import logging

# set up logging to file - see previous section for more details
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
                    filename='/temp/myapp.log',
                    filemode='w')
logger = logging.getLogger('myapp')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# define a Handler which writes INFO messages or higher to the sys.stderr
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# set a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
# tell the handler to use this format
console.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handler to your logger
logger.addHandler(console)
```

Then in my app, I logged like below just using `logger` (without any numbers).

```
logger.debug('Quick zephyrs blow, vexing daft Jim.')
logger.info('How quickly daft jumping zebras vex.')
logger.warning('Jail zesty vixen who grabbed pay from quack.')
logger.error('The five boxing wizards jump quickly.')
```